# Upload file in Spring 4 MVC java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileItemFactory

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc, file-upload

I try to write a file upload program in Spring 4 MVC. But the following exception is constantly thrown.

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileItemFactory`

I reviewed all the questions related to this issue and claim that that I made none of their mistakes.

I downloaded the **commons-fileupload:1.3.1** library from maven and added the following line to my .iml file

```
<orderEntry type="library" name="commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:1.3.1" level="project" />
```

This bean is added to spring-mvc-servlet.xml

```
<bean id="multipartResolver"
            class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">

    <!-- setting maximum upload size -->
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="100000" />

</bean>
```

Moreover I noticed that the class in the library that can not be found is crossed out(see the picture below)[image: classes are cut out]

Could not find out whether this is the main reason of the exception or these these classes are nevertheless available.

Answer (score 0):

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileItemFactory

the NoClassDefFoundError exception says that FileItemFactory class found but a exception is thrown while creating instance, this type of problems occurs when duplicate dependency jar files in classpath OR version mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and just solved it.
1) make sure commons-fileupload and commons-io both are listed as your dependencies.
2) make sure no other dependency overrides the functionality. For example Spring by default uses Servlet-api 3 upload mechanism... remove that from your project module dependencies

3) The final point that was the key solution for me is , make sure both dependencies are added to tomcat deployment. I am not able to post screen shots so I will give you the path to double check if jar are there or nor.
in Itellij Idea Project Structure --> Artifacts --> compare Available Elements with output layout.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue, in my case I discovered that commons-io dependency was in conflict, after resolve it, everything works great!

To discover conflicts, I've run:

`mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=commons-io`

The result was:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ smartplan ---
[INFO] com.claro:smartplan:war:1.15.0
[INFO] +- commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] \- org.hibernate:hibernate-search-orm:jar:4.5.1.Final:test
[INFO]    \- org.hibernate:hibernate-search-analyzers:jar:4.5.1.Final:test
[INFO]       \- org.apache.solr:solr-analysis-extras:jar:3.6.2:test
[INFO]          \- org.apache.solr:solr-core:jar:3.6.2:test
[INFO]             +- org.apache.solr:solr-solrj:jar:3.6.2:test
[INFO]             |  \- (commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.1:test - omitted for conflict with 2.2)
[INFO]             \- (commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.1:test - omitted for conflict with 2.2)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

After that, I removed conflict dependency on pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-search-orm</artifactId>
    <version>4.5.1.Final</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Look the main explanation again. ;)